# Get coordinates from a Google Maps Embed Link

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, coordinates, google-maps-embed

I'm developing an app for iPhone that uses Mapkit and I want to include the coordinates used in this [Google Maps Embed Link](https://www.google.com/maps/d/embed?mid=zZY3Uui1vIqo.khcCc7obcc5U&ie=UTF8&hl=es&msa=0&ll=41.121278,1.2137&spn=0.012447,0.070831&output=embed&s=AARTsJp61HkCwhSCGsa2dWDn_kyh9rAu3w) (I'm not the author).
The map is very simple and doesn't show the coordinates (At least I couldn't find them), so I think that analysing the link there might be useful parameters that would allow me to dump or export them. Is it possible?
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the KMZ for the map, the archive contains a KML-file with all the data:

https://www.google.com/maps/d/kml?mid=zZY3Uui1vIqo.khcCc7obcc5U